# COMException when running application in Citrix XenApp 6

Tags: c#, com, citrix, xenapp

I'm running an application that I deployed in Citrix XenApp 6 running on Windows 2008 R2 64-bit and getting the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM
>    class factory for component with CLSID {9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}
>    failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
>    from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

I found the same issue on [this MSDN topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84efe29d-28c7-45aa-b394-b6e6b7e492a4/shdocvwshellwindows-sw-new-shellwindows?forum=csharpgeneral), but I didn't grasp a solution.

Comment: It's telling you that the COM object you are trying to instantiate is not registered.

Comment: Can you tell how to register Interop.SHDocVw.dll on windows server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ShellWindows class (used to enumerate InternetExplorer windows) 
is hosted by explorer.exe process. Thus since Citrix in seamless mode does not run explorer.exe
we get exception of retrieving COM object.

Tomer

thanks.